# accessing the return value in post sharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

As I am new to post sharp this question

I create a exception aspect and  in the onexception I set this return value

```
 public class aspect:OnExceptionAspect
 {
   public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.ReturnValue=-100;
       args.FlowBehaviour=FlowBehavior.Continue;
    }
  }
```

Here I am using the aspect

```
DBLayer
{
   [ExceptionAspect()) 
    public int GetMeVal()
       {
            throw new Exception();
          //now how to get the args.returnValue of -100 here
           //remaining code needs to be executed ?
        }
}
```

HomeController

```
ControllerMethod()
{
    x=DBLayer.GetMeVal() -- Here I want the -100 to be returned
  /// need to set status code based on x value
}
```

1)Pls tell me how can I achieve the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the remaining code cannot be executed after the exception has been thrown.
After applying the aspect your method will look similarly to this (simplified):

```
public int GetMeVal()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
        // remaining code
    }
    catch
    {
        return -100;
    }
 }
```

As you can see, the exception is caught in the catch block and there is no way for remaining code to be executed. What you can try to do is to refactor your remaining code to another method or another aspect.

If you have another `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` aspect before the current aspect, then the `FlowBehavior.Return` calls the `OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs)` method of the other aspect. If applicable, you may move the "remaining code" to the `OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs)` method and access the return value with `MethodExecutionArgs.ReturnValue`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Aspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.ReturnValue=-100;
        args.FlowBehaviour=FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Aspect2 : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Return value = {0}", args.ReturnValue);
        // remaining code
    }
}

[Aspect2(AspectPriority = 1)]
[Aspect(AspectPriority = 2)]
public int GetMeVal()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this information.  Is there any way that the args.ReturnVal which contains -100 in the OnExit method can be returned as object like int or a string to the controller method.  This is required as I am going to use the retval to set a status code as I am using a MVC4 web application.

Comment: In the `OnException` you only need to set the desired `ReturnValue` and `FlowBehaviour` to `FlowBehavior.Return`.

Comment: Thanks once again, I have set those things now and also it is hitting the onexit method from on the onexit method I need to pass a integer value like -100 to the controller calling the aspect.  Can you pls tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: Hm, this change should be enough to return the value from the method as seen in your example. It doesn't work? What is returned from the GetMeVal method then? Maybe you could update the example, if it's different now that you made the changes?